# Compile time check for changes to struct in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, struct, reflection

I have a `serializable` struct in struct.h that I am serializing in serialize.h using a custom serialization method. If a change is made to my `serializable` struct I need to make sure that a corresponding change in made in serialize.h as well.
Typical method of [reflection](http://www.garret.ru/cppreflection/docs/reflect.html) use some macros for this. But the nature of our struct and the way we massage the data during serialization does not work well for this.

Is there some way to do some static compile time check so if the `serializable` struct is changed in any way without changing the serialize.h then the build will fail.

One way I have thought of but prefer to do it as last resort is to make a copy of definition of `serializable` struct in serialize.h and use [boost::is_same](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html) check with error message asking for corresponding change in serialize.h

Comment: Rather than explaining your code, please paste a text version of [mcve].

Comment: Seems like your  `struct` should be handling its own serialization, such as via virtual methods that the serialization engine calls, so the `struct` itself, not the engine, controls what is serialized and how. That way, if the struct fields are changed, all you have to do is change the struct's serialization methods to match.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Your hint may work in OPs specific case but (extending the range a bit) how could this be done if there are multiple kinds of serialization (say: writers for multiple distinct file formats)? A question over which I stumbled occasionally without having a solution at hand...

Comment: @Scheff that is a job for another set of classes to handle. Create a class for each file format, and then you can decide which format to create and to the struct. The struct decides which fields to serialize, the format classes decide how those values are formatted. For instance, the struct decides to serialize an `int` field. A JSON class decides to format that int in a JSON format. Or an XML class in XML format. Or a binary class in binary format.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sounds like a member function of the structure itself which writes into a serializer (passed as argument) of which it only knows the abstract super class... That's actually a nice idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to just do a checksum verifications for the code. If the `serializable` struct is modified then the static_assert will fail and the error message asks to update the code and the checksum.
This was a compromise we made to make code easier to read and at the same time ensure we don't forget updating serialization.